# Extract MID between characters, but from second instance in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, extract, string

I need to isolate the middle string of text from a line. The number which follows the "Q."

"400"

When I pull the MID section, it grabs everything from the FIRST "S" to the end of the "Q400"

ABS12345Q400S123456789

I'm looking for the formula to extract the middle text from the "Q" until the SECOND instance of "S."

I should add that the digits after "S" vary in length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the position of *Q* to start looking for the second *S*.

```
=--MID(A2, FIND("Q", A2)+1, FIND("S", A2, FIND("Q", A2))-FIND("Q", A2)-1)
```

Comment: Consider omitting the double unary in order to preserve any leading zero's in the substring.

Comment: That's a good idea Ron. I think I'll leave it to the OP as to whether they want true numbers or text that looks like a number (with leading zeroes).